# Parse.com QueryForTable method

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm using parse.com as database. My tableViewController, which is a class PFQueryTableViewController looks like this:

```
// Override to customize what kind of query to perform on the class. The default is to query for
// all objects ordered by createdAt descending.
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    PFQuery *exerciciosQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [exerciciosQuery includeKey:@"exercicios"];
    [exerciciosQuery findObjects];
    _exerciciosArray = [exerciciosQuery findObjects];
    NSLog(@"teste %@", _exerciciosArray);

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if ([self.objects count] == 5) {
        exerciciosQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    return exerciciosQuery;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    PFObject *exercicios = [_exerciciosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setText:[exercicios objectForKey:@"Title"]];

    return cell;
}
```

My table doesn't display anything. When I log _exerciciosArray, it looks like this:

{\n    cep = \"25553-555\";\n    cidade = \"Rio de Janeiro\";\n    email = \"blabla@globo.com\";\n    endereco = \"Rua Oscar 100/500\";\n    estado = \"Rio de Janeiro\";\n    exercicio1 = \"\";\n    exercicios =     (\n        \" {\n    Title = \\"Rosca no Pulley\\";\n}\",\n        \" {\n    Title = \\"Rosca no Pulley\\";\n}\"\n    );\n    nascimento = \"12/02/1888\";\n    nome = Jorge;\n    pais = Brasil;\n    sobrenome = Junior;\n    telefone = \"(21) 9999-9999\";\n    username = \"blabla@globo.com\";\n}"

Comment: I have been struggling with a similar issue, but in my case the query is returning 3 objects (each different from the others) when I send findObjects to the query, but then (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object is called 3 times, but all 3 times with the *same* object, which is the first one of the array of results. Did you make any progress towards finding the answer? by the way, I posted my question a few minutes ago, before I found yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PFQueryTableViewController you don't need to do `findObjects` the queryForTable will automatically send each object to `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {` so your don't need `PFObject *exercicios = [_exerciciosArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` since you are already receiving the PFObject in the method.

Just do:

```
[cell.textLabel setText:[object objectForKey:@"Title"]];
```

and remove from this `queryForTable`:

```
[exerciciosQuery findObjects];
_exerciciosArray = [exerciciosQuery findObjects];
```